# Помогите побороть CORS в AngularJS

Tags: ajax, javascript, angularjs, cors

Здравствуйте. Уже 3-й день бьюсь с проблемой отправить запрос на сервер, уже весь гугл перерыл, ничего не работает :((

Есть удалённый сайт http://site.ru/test.php
В нём лежит код

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://site.ru");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Request-Method: POST");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")

echo "Привет";
?>
```

И есть функция

```
$scope.doRegister = function () {    
        $http({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://site.ru/test.php",
            data: {
                "username": $scope.username,
                "password": $scope.password
            },
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            withCredentials: true,
        }).success(function (data) {
            alert("Успешно");   
        });
    }
```

И всё время в консоли выводит одно и тоже

```
Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://site.ru/test.php. Это может быть исправлено путем перемещения ресурса в тот же домен или включением CORS.
```

Поместить приложение на тот домен не могу, нужно удалённо, а не работает.

Comment: если в имени домена есть mlm или reklama, то сделать ajax запрос с другого домена нельзя. Это так и в ангуляре, и в jQuery.

Comment: А если другой домен будет?

Comment: Фишка в том, что и на localhost не хочет :(

Comment: на локалхост - это отдельная история. В целом, нормально будет работать только если на свой же домен. Хотите заставить работать - ищите на тему json**p**.